# Tool for class documentation auto-generation

Tags: visual-studio-code, groovy

I am starting with Groovy and I am looking for a proper environment to develop. I am currently using VS Code with some groovy included pluggin (code-groovy, [Groovy Lint, Format and Fix](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-groovy-lint)).

Any advice for a tool / pluggin to generate automatically the class documentation?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any advice for a tool / pluggin to generate automatically the class
> documentation?

For standard class level documentation you should use groovydoc/javadoc.

Comment: Do you have a tool to recommand to do it easily?

Comment: "Do you have a tool to recommand to do it easily?" - I would use groovydoc.  You can invoke it automatically from a Gradle or Maven build.